# Understanding the solution of an exercise about Gaussian and principal curvatures

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I was reading the solution to an exercise, and I don't really understand the logic passages in this sentence ($\Sigma \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ denotes a surface, and in particular the surface $\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x^2+2y^2+3z^2=6\}$, but I don't think it's relevant to the question)

> The orthogonal reflections of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with respect to the coordinate planes can be viewed as isometries $\Sigma \longrightarrow \Sigma$, and this means that the points $( \pm1,\pm1,\pm1)$ have the same principal curvatures and Gaussian curvature

It is clear to me that two isometric surfaces have the same Gaussian curvature because of the Theorema Egregium, but what about the principal curvatures? Why we can conclude the same thing?

Comment: What’s in your title is completely wrong. Even the statement is misleading. Isometries of a surface need not preserve principal curvatures. But these are isometries of $\Bbb R^3$ that preserve the surface.

Comment: @TedShifrin does this mean that there are isometries in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that don't preserve the surfaces? In what sense the statement is misleading?

Comment: The sentence suggests that an intrinsic isometry (rather than ambient isometry) will have this property. It preserves Gaussian curvature (by the Theorema Egregium), but need not preserve extrinsic geometry. The standard example that comes to my mind, however, is an isometry between different surfaces.

Comment: @TedShifrin so why it concludes that the principal curvatures are the same? This is what bothers me. And also, is it correct to say that an isometry on all $\mathbb{R}^3$ (like in this case) is a local isometry from a surface to itself?

Comment: Yes, if you have an isometry of $\Bbb R^3$ that carries the surface to itself, then it gives an isometry of the surface to itself. This is because the metric structure of the surface is induced from its embedding in $\Bbb R^3$ to start with. The point is that the isometries of $\Bbb R^3$ are just rotations, reflections, and translations (thus, all built out of orthogonal linear maps and translations) and you just can compute and check that the first and second fundamental forms are preserved (the latter up to sign).